# I can not handle an exception error in my PHP project in which I make use of Laravel

Tags: laravel, php

I have a following restful function in my controller

```
public function get_index()
{
    return Event::all();
}
```

But it returns following error

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Call to undefined method Laravel\Event::all()
Location:

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/calendar/application/controllers/home.php on line 8
```

Here is my complete controller

```
class Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index()
    {
        return Event::all();
    }

}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the `Event` class? Apparently it has no `all()` method.

Comment: Event is a model. I want to retrive data from database using all() function.

Comment: Maerlyn is right, there is no all() method for the Event class. So unless you have implemented a custom event for all() yourself you probably need to remove that line.

Comment: Laravel has this method but no idea why it is not working.

Comment: @x4ph4r: then rename or namespace your model, currently laravel is thinking that you are trying to run all() on the Events class - not the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces and classes have to be registered.

```php
//application/start.php

Autoloader::map(array(
    'Modelpath' => path('event').'models/event.php', //path to your directory and class
));

Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Model' => path('Modelpath'),
));
```

If you don't like to call your class with it's namespace you could define an alias for it:

```
//application/config/application
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Event' => 'models\\Event' //path and filaname of your class without extension
),
```

Answer (score 3):

Again you need to namespace your Model, you are conflicting with Laravel's built in Events class.

```
<?php namespace Model;

class Event {

}
```

And then when you want to call it you call it with `return Model\Event::all();`